# Realtime yolov5 detection with Desktop screen as input

Tags: python, opencv, yolov5

I have a script that grabs an application's screenshot and displays it. it works quite nicely on my machine like a video with around 60FPS.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import time
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
os.system('calc')
sct = mss()
xx=1
tstart = time.time()
while xx<10000:
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')
    left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    #screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab( bbox = (left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y ) ) )
    bbox = {'top': top_y, 'left': left_x, 'width': right_x-left_x, 'height':bottom_y-top_y }
    screen = sct.grab(bbox)
    scr = np.array(screen)
    
    cv2.imshow('window', scr)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    xx+=1
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
tend = time.time()
print(xx/(tend-tstart))
print((tend-tstart))
os.system('taskkill /f /im calculator.exe')
```

I would like to run yolov5's `detect.py` on this `scr` image without having to save to disk all the time. I'd also like to show the images with bounding boxes and have their coordinates saved somewhere.

My python level is not good enough, I tried importing `detect` and adding arguments, but it doesn't seem like it accepts any function parameter, only command line arguments.

Perhaps I should adapt this line, or use opencv?

```
parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default='data/images', help='source')  # file/folder, 0 for webcam
```

Any idea? thanks (this is the `detect.py` file for yolov5)

```
import argparse
import time
from pathlib import Path

import cv2
import torch
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
from numpy import random

from models.experimental import attempt_load
from utils.datasets import LoadStreams, LoadImages
from utils.general import check_img_size, non_max_suppression, apply_classifier, scale_coords, xyxy2xywh, \
    strip_optimizer, set_logging, increment_path
from utils.plots import plot_one_box
from utils.torch_utils import select_device, load_classifier, time_synchronized


    def detect(save_img=False):
        source, weights, view_img, save_txt, imgsz = opt.source, opt.weights, opt.view_img, opt.save_txt, opt.img_size
        webcam = source.isnumeric() or source.endswith('.txt') or source.lower().startswith(
            ('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://'))
    
        # Directories
        save_dir = Path(increment_path(Path(opt.project) / opt.name, exist_ok=opt.exist_ok))  # increment run
        (save_dir / 'labels' if save_txt else save_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make dir
    
        # Initialize
        set_logging()
        device = select_device(opt.device)
        half = device.type != 'cpu'  # half precision only supported on CUDA
    
        # Load model
        model = attempt_load(weights, map_location=device)  # load FP32 model
        imgsz = check_img_size(imgsz, s=model.stride.max())  # check img_size
        if half:
            model.half()  # to FP16
    
        # Second-stage classifier
        classify = False
        if classify:
            modelc = load_classifier(name='resnet101', n=2)  # initialize
            modelc.load_state_dict(torch.load('weights/resnet101.pt', map_location=device)['model']).to(device).eval()
    
        # Set Dataloader
        vid_path, vid_writer = None, None
        if webcam:
            view_img = True
            cudnn.benchmark = True  # set True to speed up constant image size inference
            dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz)
        else:
            save_img = True
            dataset = LoadImages(source, img_size=imgsz)
    
        # Get names and colors
        names = model.module.names if hasattr(model, 'module') else model.names
        colors = [[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)] for _ in names]
    
        # Run inference
        t0 = time.time()
        img = torch.zeros((1, 3, imgsz, imgsz), device=device)  # init img
        _ = model(img.half() if half else img) if device.type != 'cpu' else None  # run once
        for path, img, im0s, vid_cap in dataset:
            img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(device)
            img = img.half() if half else img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            img /= 255.0  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
            if img.ndimension() == 3:
                img = img.unsqueeze(0)
    
            # Inference
            t1 = time_synchronized()
            pred = model(img, augment=opt.augment)[0]
    
            # Apply NMS
            pred = non_max_suppression(pred, opt.conf_thres, opt.iou_thres, classes=opt.classes, agnostic=opt.agnostic_nms)
            t2 = time_synchronized()
    
            # Apply Classifier
            if classify:
                pred = apply_classifier(pred, modelc, img, im0s)
    
            # Process detections
            for i, det in enumerate(pred):  # detections per image
                if webcam:  # batch_size >= 1
                    p, s, im0 = Path(path[i]), '%g: ' % i, im0s[i].copy()
                else:
                    p, s, im0 = Path(path), '', im0s
    
                save_path = str(save_dir / p.name)
                txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('_%g' % dataset.frame if dataset.mode == 'video' else '')
                s += '%gx%g ' % img.shape[2:]  # print string
                gn = torch.tensor(im0.shape)[[1, 0, 1, 0]]  # normalization gain whwh
                if len(det):
                    # Rescale boxes from img_size to im0 size
                    det[:, :4] = scale_coords(img.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()
    
                    # Print results
                    for c in det[:, -1].unique():
                        n = (det[:, -1] == c).sum()  # detections per class
                        s += '%g %ss, ' % (n, names[int(c)])  # add to string
    
                    # Write results
                    for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
                        if save_txt:  # Write to file
                            xywh = (xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view(1, 4)) / gn).view(-1).tolist()  # normalized xywh
                            line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if opt.save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # label format
                            with open(txt_path + '.txt', 'a') as f:
                                f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')
    
                        if save_img or view_img:  # Add bbox to image
                            label = '%s %.2f' % (names[int(cls)], conf)
                            plot_one_box(xyxy, im0, label=label, color=colors[int(cls)], line_thickness=3)
    
                # Print time (inference + NMS)
                print('%sDone. (%.3fs)' % (s, t2 - t1))
    
                # Stream results
                if view_img:
                    cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):  # q to quit
                        raise StopIteration
    
                # Save results (image with detections)
                if save_img:
                    if dataset.mode == 'images':
                        cv2.imwrite(save_path, im0)
                    else:
                        if vid_path != save_path:  # new video
                            vid_path = save_path
                            if isinstance(vid_writer, cv2.VideoWriter):
                                vid_writer.release()  # release previous video writer
    
                            fourcc = 'mp4v'  # output video codec
                            fps = vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
                            w = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
                            h = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
                            vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*fourcc), fps, (w, h))
                        vid_writer.write(im0)
    
        if save_txt or save_img:
            s = f"\n{len(list(save_dir.glob('labels/*.txt')))} labels saved to {save_dir / 'labels'}" if save_txt else ''
            print(f"Results saved to {save_dir}{s}")
    
        print('Done. (%.3fs)' % (time.time() - t0))
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, default='yolov5s.pt', help='model.pt path(s)')
        parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default='data/images', help='source')  # file/folder, 0 for webcam
        parser.add_argument('--img-size', type=int, default=640, help='inference size (pixels)')
        parser.add_argument('--conf-thres', type=float, default=0.25, help='object confidence threshold')
        parser.add_argument('--iou-thres', type=float, default=0.45, help='IOU threshold for NMS')
        parser.add_argument('--device', default='', help='cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu')
        parser.add_argument('--view-img', action='store_true', help='display results')
        parser.add_argument('--save-txt', action='store_true', help='save results to *.txt')
        parser.add_argument('--save-conf', action='store_true', help='save confidences in --save-txt labels')
        parser.add_argument('--classes', nargs='+', type=int, help='filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3')
        parser.add_argument('--agnostic-nms', action='store_true', help='class-agnostic NMS')
        parser.add_argument('--augment', action='store_true', help='augmented inference')
        parser.add_argument('--update', action='store_true', help='update all models')
        parser.add_argument('--project', default='runs/detect', help='save results to project/name')
        parser.add_argument('--name', default='exp', help='save results to project/name')
        parser.add_argument('--exist-ok', action='store_true', help='existing project/name ok, do not increment')
        opt = parser.parse_args()
        print(opt)
    
        with torch.no_grad():
            if opt.update:  # update all models (to fix SourceChangeWarning)
                for opt.weights in ['yolov5s.pt', 'yolov5m.pt', 'yolov5l.pt', 'yolov5x.pt']:
                    detect()
                    strip_optimizer(opt.weights)
            else:
                detect()
```

---

**EDIT** I already have weights saved somewhere and am able to run `detect` on images that are saved on disc, just would like to skip this step to keep those FPS.
The Yolov5 repo is [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standalone inference in 3rd party projects or repos importing your model into the python workspace with PyTorch Hub is the recommended method. See YOLOv5 PyTorch Hub tutorial here, specifically the section on loading custom models.
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5#tutorials

### Custom Models

This example loads a custom 20-class [VOC](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/data/voc.yaml)-trained YOLOv5s model `'yolov5s_voc_best.pt'` with PyTorch Hub.

```py
import torch

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path_or_model='yolov5s_voc_best.pt')
model = model.autoshape()  # for PIL/cv2/np inputs and NMS
```

Then once the model is loaded:

```py
from PIL import Image

# Images
img1 = Image.open('zidane.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('bus.jpg')
imgs = [img1, img2]  # batched list of images

# Inference
result = model(imgs, size=640)  # includes NMS
result.print()
```

Comment: Why is it important to pass the size? Is it important for the trained model? Is it the size of quadratic image which the model is build for?

Comment: @programmar image size is the image size in pixels (long side). If you don't pass any default value 640 is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import torch
from mss import mss
import numpy as np


model = torch.hub.load("/yolov5", 'custom', path="yolov5/best.pt", source='local')

sct = mss()

while 1:
    w, h = 1920, 1080
    monitor = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': w, 'height': h}
    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (w, h), sct.grab(monitor).rgb)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    # set the model use the screen
    result = model(screen, size=640)
    cv2.imshow('Screen', result.render()[0])

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

im a noob in programming
and using desktop screen to run inference can be found in yolov5's github page
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36

```
import cv2
import numpy
import torch
from mss import mss
from PIL import ImageGrab


im = numpy.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1080)))
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
model.conf = 0.6
image = r'D:\i\test\yolov5-master(original)\yolov5-master\data\images\zidane.jpg'
results = model(im)
results.print()
results.show()
print(results.pandas().xyxy[0])
```

i have found mss().grab() have an rgb order issue, so use PIL instead