# PyTorch with yolov5: color channel and result display

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, yolo

I have a script that grabs an application's screenshot and displays it. it works quite nicely on my machine like a video with around 60FPS. Now I want to use a yolov5 object detection model on these frames, with TorchHub, as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312850/python-detect-yolov5-from-screen-as-video-source).

The following works:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import time
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
os.system('calc')
sct = mss()
xx=1
tstart = time.time()
while xx<10000:
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')
    left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    #screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab( bbox = (left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y ) ) )
    bbox = {'top': top_y, 'left': left_x, 'width': right_x-left_x, 'height':bottom_y-top_y }
    screen = sct.grab(bbox)
    scr = np.array(screen)
    
    cv2.imshow('window', scr)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    xx+=1
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
tend = time.time()
print(xx/(tend-tstart))
print((tend-tstart))
os.system('taskkill /f /im calculator.exe')
```

Below I try to `import torch` and use my previously trained model,

```
screen = sct.grab(bbox)
scr = np.array(screen)    
result = model(scr, size=400)  
result.save("test.png") #this gives a TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
result.show() #this opens a new Paint instance for every frame instead of keeping the same window. 
# The shown image is also in a wrong color channel
scr = cv2.imread("test.png")
# How can I use the `result` as argument to cv2.imshow(),
# without saving to disk if possible?
```

My questions:

1. `result.show()` shows an image with wrong color channel compared to `cv2.imshow()`, how can I ensure that the image being fed to `model` is on the correct channel?
2. The performance of classification and detection drastically decrease compared to the training validation, perhaps because of 1?
3. Do you know how I can display the result model image with bounding boxes in a single window like what `cv2.imshow()` does ? (`result.show()` opens a new Paint process instance for each frame) ? How can I save this result image to disk and find more documentation on how to interact with `model` objects in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked: `result = model(cv2.cvtColor(scr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), size=400)`
This solved the accuracy problem and `model.save()` has pre-defined output names  which are not currently changeable, it takes no arguments.
`model.show()` shows the correct color channel output when fed the correct color channel as input.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cvtColor operation should be identical to the provided channel order inversion shown in the YOLOv5 PyTorch Hub [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/hub/ultralytics_yolov5/). This returns `True` in two environments tested (colab notebook python 3.6 and MacOS python 3.9)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = 'data/images/bus.jpg'
im1 = cv2.imread(file)[:, :, ::-1]
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(file), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(np.allclose(im1, im2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 3:
You can render boxes and labels on image with function `render()`, and then use `cv::imshow` for display in needed window:

```
renderedResult = result.render()
cv2.imshow("Result", renderedResult[0])
```